# Storing function and arguments in a list

Tags: python

I'm wanting to store multiple functions in a list. I have multiple of those lists stored in a dictionary. I want to later call those functions, based on the list that is active at that time. However, I not only want to store the functions, I also want to add multiple arguments.

Edit: The lists are lists of buttons. When the button is pressed, the function should run. One of the functions is used to swap between 'layers' of buttons.

However when initializing the list, the functions are called. I only want this to happen when the button is pressed.

Is there a way to work around this, or is there a better way to store my data?

```py
dictionary = {
  "example1" : [function1(argument), function2(argument), function4(argument)],
  "example2" : [function1(argument), function5(argument), function3(argument)],
  "example3" : [function1(argument), function3(argument), function5(argument), function1(argument)],
  "example4" : [function3(argument, argument2],
  "example5" : []
}
```

Comment: Please show how you wish to use this dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## avoiding evaluating the function object

To avoid evaluating the function you have to pass the function itself. There are lots of ways to do this, for example:

```py
e = "something"

func = lambda: print(e)

func()

e = "another thing"

func()
```

out:

```
something
another thing
```

which if you wanted to use with a dictionary would work as follows:

```py
dictionary = {"some_func": lambda: function1(argument)}
dictionary["some_func"]()  # argument is is passed to function1, changeable after the declaration
```

As has been covered in the answers already, you can also use functools to achieve this.

## brief coverage of arguments and functions

if you just want to store the function definition for calling with arbitrary arguments later:

```py
def some_func(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    args is a tuple of type tuple[Any,...],
    kwargs is a dict of type dict[str, Any]
    """
    for arg in args:
        # do something with your positional args
        print(arg)

dictionary = {"some_func": some_func} # pass the function like so

dictionary["some_func"]("some_arg")
```

Out:

```
some_arg
```

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter said, you can use  [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to store the function to evaluate later.

Here's a full example:

```py
import functools


def function1(arg1, arg2):
    print("function1: ", arg1, arg2)


dictionary = {
    "example1": functools.partial(function1, "arg1", "arg2"),
}

dictionary["example1"]()
# prints: function1:  arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

functools.partial works as per the comment.  However, see the output below.

EDIT: Also ninja-ed by Ben

```
from functools import partial

def this(in_str):
    print(f'{in_str}')
    
def that(in_str, in_key=''):
    print(f'{in_str} {in_key}')
    
foo = {'example_1': [partial(this, 'why'), partial(that,'are',in_key='you')],
       'example_2': [partial(this, 'doing'), partial(that,'this')],
       }

for key, val in foo.items():
    for your_func in val:
        your_func()
```

Out:

```
why
are you
doing
this
```